# Can I touch the leaves of my pinguicula?

Tags: leaves, carnivorous-plants

Is it safe for both me and the plant if I touch the leaves of my pinguicula plants? Are there any precautions I should take or things I should avoid doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After over a year of dealing with mine: Perfectly safe to touch them. The slime rubs off of skin easily with no residue.

They are sturdier than they look, but avoid sharp or hard objects (such as long fingernails or tweezers), since it's relatively easy to pierce the leaves. They can be slippery to hold when taking leaf pullings, best to grasp the plant (the whole plant, not the container) in one hand and just the leaf you want to remove with the other hand--being careful of your fingernails as mentioned.